# How to make like and addtocart icons toggle appearance

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fbsdklikebutton

I'm trying to run a simple like and addtocart functionality whereby when the user clicks on the icons, it immediately toggles to a filled up or different color icon. However, the parent div's link is also inherited so I added a stopPropagation to the script. I did not add in html & script code for #addtocart yet as the function is going to be similar to the #heart like icon.

The issue is, the toggle is not working + my editor gives me an "Error: $undefined" msg even though I'm linking my javascript correctly. I would appreciate it if someone can help to point out where I went wrong. I would eventually like to add in the functionality whereby clicking on the icons will add the product to a user's wishlist or cart page, but I've yet to learn how to code back-end, so I just render the UI for now. However, if you can tell me how I can make the icons link to the user's wishlist or cart page and not inherit the parent's link, that would be great.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#heart').click(function() {
    $('#heart--liked').toggle('1000');
  });
  $("#heart a").click(function(e) {
    //do something to stop link # from loading
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
});
```

```css
.product__list__item {
  border-radius: 2px;
  background-color: var(--pure-white);
  border: solid 1px var(--dark-grey);
}

.product__list__item--description {
  padding: 1.5rem;
  text-align: left;
}

.product__list__item h3 {
  margin-bottom: .75rem;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}

.product__list__item--icons {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  padding-top: 5px;
}

.product__list__item--icons a {
  color: var(--middle-grey);
}

.product__list__item--icons a:hover {
  color: var(--dark-grey);
}

#heart--liked {
  display: none;
  transition: .2s;
}

#addtocart {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.product__list__item--price {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  color: var(--dark-gray);
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  text-align: right;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.price--hot {
  color: var(--crimson-red);
}

.price--display {
  color: var(--pompeian-pink);
}

.product__list__item--description h3 sup {
  font-size: .875rem;
  padding: 5px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  vertical-align: super;
}

.price__sale {
  text-decoration: line-through;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  color: var(--highlight-gray);
  margin-left: 5px;
  vertical-align: sub;
}

.product__list__item--description:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.11/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-p2jx59pefphTFIpeqCcISO9MdVfIm4pNnsL08A6v5vaQc4owkQqxMV8kg4Yvhaw/" crossorigin="anonymous">


</head>

<body>
  <div class="product__list__item">
    <a href="#" class="image-container">
      <div class="image-container__wrapper">
        <div class="image-container--mask">
          <h4>View details</h4>
        </div>
        <img src="https://foter.com/photos/235/design-tree-home-acapulco-lounge-chair-yellow-1.jpg?s=pi" alt="yellow chair">
      </div>
      <div class="product__list__item--description">
        <h3>Yellow Chair<sup class="price--hot">Clearance!</sup></h3>
        <div class="product__list__item--icons">
          <span id="heart"><a href=" "><i class="far fa-heart fa-2x"></i><i id="heart--liked" class="fas fa-heart fa-2x"></i></a></span>
          <span id="addtocart"><a href=" "><i class="fas fa-cart-plus fa-2x"></i></a></span>
        </div>
        <div class="product__list__item--price price--hot">$189
          <sub class="price__sale">$109</sub>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use a class to change the color when you click.

See below a working snippet where I tried to respect your way of doing:
I added CSS variables to the body to make it work, and some comments where I added/modified things.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // Specific code for the heart fill toggle
  $("#heart--liked").click(function(e) {
    $(this).toggleClass("far").toggleClass("fas"); // Toggle the filling !
  });

  // Action when click on a link (color)
  $(".product__list__item--icons a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // Modified: stop link # from loading (Why using link then?)
    $(this).toggleClass("selected"); // Toggle the colored class !
  });

});
```

```css
.product__list__item {
  border-radius: 2px;
  background-color: var(--pure-white);
  border: solid 1px var(--dark-grey);
}

.product__list__item--description {
  padding: 1.5rem;
  text-align: left;
}

.product__list__item h3 {
  margin-bottom: .75rem;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}

.product__list__item--icons {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  padding-top: 5px;
}

.product__list__item--icons a {
  color: var(--middle-grey);
}

.product__list__item--icons a:hover {
  color: var(--dark-grey);
}


/* Added the two below */

.product__list__item--icons .selected {
  color: var(--light-pink);
}

.product__list__item--icons .selected:hover {
  color: var(--pink);
}

#heart--liked {
  /*display: none; REMOVED */
  transition: .2s;
}

#addtocart {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.product__list__item--price {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  color: var(--dark-gray);
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  text-align: right;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.price--hot {
  color: var(--crimson-red);
}

.price--display {
  color: var(--pompeian-pink);
}

.product__list__item--description h3 sup {
  font-size: .875rem;
  padding: 5px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  vertical-align: super;
}

.price__sale {
  text-decoration: line-through;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  color: var(--highlight-gray);
  margin-left: 5px;
  vertical-align: sub;
}

.product__list__item--description:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.11/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-p2jx59pefphTFIpeqCcISO9MdVfIm4pNnsL08A6v5vaQc4owkQqxMV8kg4Yvhaw/" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body style="--middle-grey: #888; --dark-grey: #444; --light-pink: #ffb6c1; --pink: #dd888b;">
  <div class="product__list__item">
    <a href="#" class="image-container">
      <div class="image-container__wrapper">
        <div class="image-container--mask">
          <h4>View details</h4>
        </div>
        <img src="https://foter.com/photos/235/design-tree-home-acapulco-lounge-chair-yellow-1.jpg?s=pi" alt="yellow chair">
      </div>
      <div class="product__list__item--description">
        <h3>Yellow Chair<sup class="price--hot">Clearance!</sup></h3>
        <div class="product__list__item--icons">
          <span id="heart"><a href=" "><i id="heart--liked" class="far fa-heart fa-2x"></i></a></span>
          <span id="addtocart"><a href=" "><i class="fas fa-cart-plus fa-2x"></i></a></span>
        </div>
        <div class="product__list__item--price price--hot">$189
          <sub class="price__sale">$109</sub>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks! The solution certainly does work especially for changing the color of the cart. However, I was trying to replicate my heart filled toggle as per this codepen snippet of mine but with awesome font icons, reason being I need the heart shape to be filled when clicked on, but empty when un-clicked: https://codepen.io/helloyellowmellowcello/pen/ZxJgyO

Comment: @Jasmine I'm gonna edit my answer. The heart class can be changed from `far` to `fas` to fill the icon. :)

Comment: thanks! it works! I'm curious though, how come I couldn't select the icons using #id, but when it came to using classes, it worked?

Comment: @Jasmine In fact, in your snippet, the second element is `displayed: none` when your document is loaded. So you can't click on it. I was using only classes to make my code also applicable to the cart element. The id on the heart icon could be added back. I am editing with it.

Answer (score -1):

$ is undefined because you have the name inside brackets. so you just have lots of variables with no name...

```
   $document.ready(function() {
      $heart.click(function() {
        $heart-liked.toggle('1000');
      });
      $heart.a.click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
      });
    });
```